# In Pandas how can I test whether a value exists in two dataframes given a unique ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this where both frames can have multiple entries for each ID:

The first dataframe df1:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | $30 |
| 102 | $300 |
| 101 | $35 |
| 103 | $10 |
| 104 | $220 |
| 103 | $370 |
| 101 | $500 |
| 105 | $65 |

The second dataframe df2 has fewer rows but the same kind of information:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | $35 |
| 102 | $2 |
| 103 | $25 |
| 104 | $75 |
| 101 | $30 |
| 102 | $900 |

I want to compare the dataframes and find any rows that have the same Amount for a given ID in both frames. Here, for example, I want pandas to return ID 101 has having an entry for $30 in both frames. Right now my intuition is to append the dataframes like so:

```
df1 = df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
df1[df1.duplicated()]
```

But I wanted to know if there's a more 'pythonic' way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want something like inner join between dataframes. You can use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["ID", "Amount"])
```